# CDbConnection.connectionString cannot be empty

Tags: mysql, yii

I working with yii framework now. created one project name -"yii".
In that project i have demo folder in which one another first

```
                         yii/demo/first
```

In that folder i had created

```
yii/demo/first/
              ->protected->config->main.php
              ->controller->SiteController.php
              ->view->site->view.php
```

I am also placing one **screen shot** to show above..

In main file i had placed connection string as shown in screenshot

[image]

I had also created database name as "student" in mysql

still when i run this site i get error like

[image]

**I had placed connection string still showing that error.**

If any mistake in above code that please tell me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try this code in `main.php` file inside `components`.

**protected/config/main.php**

```
'components' => array(
  'db'=>array(
       // Add hostname, port number, dbnanme
      'connectionString'  => 'mysql:host=hostname;port=5432;dbname=dname',
      'emulatePrepare'    => true,
      'username'          => "username", // Add db Username
      'password'          => "password", // Add Db Password
      'charset'           => 'utf8',
      'schemaCachingDuration' => 3600,
  ),
),
```